# Get the value of hidden field in same html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of `hidden` field in my html.

```
<form>

<fieldset>
<input id="name" type="hidden" value="vikiiii" name="name">
</fieldset>

My name is {What should i write here to print "vikiiii" ???} ...!!!

</div>

</form>
```

How i can print my name in that same html.

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this HTML

```
<form>

<fieldset>
<input id="name" type="hidden" value="vikiiii" name="name">
</fieldset>

My name is <span id="nameTarget"></span> ...!!!

</div>

</form>
```

This JavaScript code will work:

```
document.getElementById( 'nameTarget' ).innerHTML = document.getElementById( 'name' ).value;
```

Comment: @vikiiii : yes it will work in jsp

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `<span>` for the value to be printed.
Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/HdZeR/).

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<input id="name" type="hidden" value="vikiiii" name="name">
</fieldset>
<span>My name is </span><span id="myname"></span><br />
```

Javascript:

```
var hiddenValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.getElementById("myname").innerText = hiddenValue;
```